# Batch decline recurring meetings

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have received hundreds of repeating meeting invitations. When I decline them they still appear in my calendar. There are too many to decline one at a time. How do I removed a batch of meetings all at once?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cancel-all-future-meetings-in-a-series-9eaeee8c-bfe3-46a0-a092-9a2707f3b133

Comment: For one meeting that repeats "n" times, there is an option in Outlook to delete the entire list of meetings. Use that.

Answer (score 0):

You could batch decline recurring meetings both via Outlook settings or the VBA method. Check the information in this article:[Ways to Batch Delete All Future Occurrences of Multiple Recurring Outlook Appointments](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-quick-ways-batch-delete-future-occurrences-multiple-recurring-outlook-appointments/).